# my numeric key pad does not display the key press in the password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am doing exercise from the book "**building-cross-platform-mobile-pawan-lingras**"
but the numeric key pad does not display the value in the text box every time I click on a keypad.

I have linked the html file with JS file and bootstrap already.

Below is the  code sample for html:

```
 Password:<input type="password" id="passcode"></input>
 -----
 ----
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a data-role="button"   onclick="addValueToPassword(4)">4</a>
        <a data-role="button"   onclick="addValueToPassword(5)">5</a>
        <a data-role="button"   onclick="addValueToPassword(6)">6</a>
    </div>
```

javaScript sample:

```
function addValueToPassword(button)
{
var currVal=$("passcode").val();
if(button=='bksp')
{
    $("#passcode").val(currVal.substring(0, currVal.length-1));
}
else{
    $("#passcode").val(currVal.concat(button));
}
}
```

Comment: any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed **#** symbol in var `currVal=$("#passcode").val()` line. jQuery will not be able to find the DOM element passcode so `$("passcode").val()` returns **undefined**. When you call **concat funtion** on undefined, it throws exception. You can replace if...else with ternary operator as below.

```
function addValueToPassword(button)
{
  var currVal=$("#passcode").val();
  let passCode = button === 'bksp' ? currVal.substring(0, currVal.length-1) : currVal.concat(button);
  $("#passcode").val(passCode);
}
```

```js
function addValueToPassword(button)
{
  var currVal=$("#passcode").val();
  if(button=='bksp')
  {
      $("#passcode").val(currVal.substring(0, currVal.length-1));
  }
  else
  {
      $("#passcode").val(currVal.concat(button));
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Password:<input type="password" id="passcode"></input>

 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <a data-role="button"   onclick="addValueToPassword(4)">4</a>
        <a data-role="button"   onclick="addValueToPassword(5)">5</a>
        <a data-role="button"   onclick="addValueToPassword(6)">6</a>
    </div>
```